# How to get around calling base class constructor from derived class with the same arguments?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

I want to use a base object that defines an "interface" and then have derived objects implement it. Every object is initialized with its name which is always the same process: Writing to a member "name_" with parameter passed to the constructor. I want to have derived objects behave exactly the same way as the base object in that regard, so every derived object should write to its name varialbe. However, the problem is that I would need to define an extra constructor in *every* derived object that writes to the name variable which is cumbersome. The following example does not compile because of this reason. Is there any way around this or is inheritance even the right approach (please feel free to suggest otherwise)?

**Non-compiling code** (shows what I want to do):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    const std::string name_;
    public:
        A(const std::string name) : name_(name) { std::cout << "creation of object " << name_ << "; this name = " << this->name_ << '\n'; }
};

class B : public A {
    // const std::string name_; -- we do not even need this because "name_" also exists for object B.

    // C++ misses its constructor here :') - I don't
};

int main()
{
    A obj_a{ "A" };

    B obj_b{ "B" };
}
```

**Associated error(s)**:

```
source>:20:18: error: no matching function for call to 'B::B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   20 |     B obj_b{ "B" };
      |                  ^
<source>:12:7: note: candidate: 'B::B(const B&)'
   12 | class B : public A {
      |       ^
<source>:12:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [2]' to 'const B&'
<source>:12:7: note: candidate: 'B::B(B&&)'
<source>:12:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [2]' to 'B&&'
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:20:18: error: no matching function for call to 'B::B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   20 |     B obj_b{ "B" };
      |                  ^
<source>:12:7: note: candidate: 'B::B(const B&)'
   12 | class B : public A {
      |       ^
<source>:12:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [2]' to 'const B&'
<source>:12:7: note: candidate: 'B::B(B&&)'
<source>:12:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [2]' to 'B&&'
```

Comment: `B(const std::string name) : A(name) {}`

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want :) I want to have NO constructor whatsoever in class B

Comment: Your complaint would be correct for a virtual function. However, a constructor cannot be virtual **by definition**.

Comment: I don't need it to be virtual, I just want class B to "copy" the defined constructors over from class A without me having to do anything

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how the rules of the language have been defined.

Comment: `using A::A;` in `B` will let you "inherit" A's constructors.

Comment: Well is there another way? I have say 20 derived objects. Very cumbersome to always go back and change those little things... I don't even need classes, I thought of maybe structs with function pointers as variables or something.

Comment: From cppreference: [inheriting constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors)

Comment: C++ simply doesn't work this way. If you want to inherit constructors, you have to state that explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a [using-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) to

> #### Using-declaration
>
> [...] introduce base class members into derived class definitions.
>
> [...]
>
> **[Inheriting constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors)**
>
> If the using-declaration refers to a constructor of a direct base of the class being defined (e.g. using `Base::Base;`), **all constructors of that base** (ignoring member access) **are made visible to overload resolution when initializing the derived class**.
>
> If overload resolution selects an inherited constructor, it is accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class: **the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced it is ignored.**

as such:

```
class B : public A {
    using A::A;
};
```

Note the highlight that the accessibility of the using-declaration itself is ignored, meaning `using A::A` in the example needn't the be placed under `public` accessibility - what matters is the accessibility of the inherited constructors in `B`.

Comment: My lord it is possible! I didn't know this existed. This way I get around redefining the parameter list every time, which is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot! Is this C++11 ready?

Comment: @glades Yes, inheriting constructors was introduced for C++11 as part of [N2512](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2512.html).

Answer (score 0):

Even add explicitly B constructor

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(const std::string& s) : A(s) {}
};
```

or "use" the base's ones

```
class B : public A
{
public:
   using A::A;
};
```